# How do you describe a castle like this (picture)?

Tags: adjectives, literary-techniques, image-identification

Credit: [Gothic Castle](http://marinaortega.deviantart.com/art/Gothic-castle-453675775) by MarinaOrtega, via DeviantArt.com

[image: image of Gothic castle in black and white]

What words or phrases or sentences that you can think of to depict this Gothic castle precisely? By precisely I mean people can visualise the image in their head by reading the descriptive sentences without seeing the illustration.

Comment: Eerie, spooky, dark, elevated, gloomy, uninviting, unwelcoming...

Comment: We don't seem to have a tag for "1000 word request".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would start with the word you used, **gothic**.  That castle has all the traits of **gothic** architecture.  You could describe it by describing its parts in more detail.

The image contains **assymetrical** *flying buttresses*:

[image: flying buttresses]

and *pointed arches*:

[image: pointed arches]

and it has **protuberant** *spires*:

[image]

It is also **ornate**, **bleak**, **sinister**, but ultimately, I don't think that is a ***photo***. :)

Comment: Lol, my bad. I've changed it to "illustration". Your answer helps a lot! Thank you!

Comment: @AssenRobin, I believe the spires in your illustration are called "needle spires".

Comment: here's a quick handy tip to resize images if you ever need to. Add **m** (medium) just before the file tag, e.g. Before https://i.stack.imgur.com/avgWQ.jpg and after https://i.stack.imgur.com/avgWQm.jpg